# Alarm will not be triggered in Python 2.7 program

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make a command line alarm clock application. The way it's supposed to work is that when the current hour and the current minute are the same as the hour and minute you want to wake up at, it will exit the `while` loop and wake you up. However, when the hour and the minute are the same as the current it just keeps going. I've attempted to google for an answer but I haven't been able to find relevant information.

```
import sys
import datetime

a = 0
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

print current_time.hour
print current_time.minute



wakehour = raw_input("When do you wanna wake up?\n What hour? Use the 24-hour clock.\n>>>")
wakeminute = raw_input("How many minutes after the hour?\n>>>")

print wakehour
print wakeminute

while a == 0:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print current_time.hour
    print current_time.minute
    if current_time.hour == wakehour and current_time.minute == wakeminute:
            print 'wakey wakey'
            a = 1
```

Comment: So, you're okay with your program pegging one core at 100% until it "wakes up"?

Comment: I'm going to change that later so that it isn't doing that constantly until the alarm-time happens. It isn't a complete program yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask a `raw_input` the result is a string:

```
>>> a=raw_input()
1
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
```

But `current_time.hour` is an int:

```
>>> current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(current_time.hour)
<type 'int'>
```

So, try to convert `wakehour`/`wakeminute` to int before the conversion with `int(wakehour)`